# Why can't I show every graduation of the x axis of a graph?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'm currently trying to make a graph on Excel based on a specific dataset. The dataset is formatted in a way that I have never encountered before and I think it's the reason why I don't figure how to show every graduation of the X axis of my graph.

## The Dataset

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Gx2P.png

I have made availible a copy of the Excel file via my Google Drive if you want to see it by yourself : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pwuxiPw00hhGTwH0vUPKzlv99UZzGqAV/view?usp=sharing.

## The Graph

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctn4D.png

I don't understand why I can't show every graduation on the X axis of the graph. The graph is showing "2000Q1, 2000Q3, 2001Q1, 2000Q3..." and I would want something like "2000Q1, 2000Q2, 2000Q3, 2000Q4...".

And when I go into the parameters of the graph and to the graduation category, I don't find an option helping me.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZ5JZ.png

*Sorry, my Excel is in French...*

If anyone could help me to arrange the X axis to show every graduation that would be awesome, thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Right click on the chart, select Format Chart Area
2. On your chart, select the x-axis elements.
3. On the Format Axis, select Axis options -> Labels (Etiquettes in your case). Change the Interval between labels from Automatic to Specify Interval unit.

You will be able to see all your elements. You will need to increase the chart size to view them properly as they are too close to each other.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much ! That was right in front of me but I couldn't see it...